# What are the Steps for installing datree in windows?

Tags: kubernetes

First I installed datree using `iwr -useb https://get.datree.io/windows_install.ps1 | iex`
then I runned `datree config set token vFXosgxFkoAdyeCssPK` but this is throwing this error
`'datree' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

[datree is not recogized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOUsF.png)

Answer (score 0):

After installation, you need to add Datree to your PATH, by running this in your terminal:

```
setx PATH "$env:path;C:\Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\datree" -m
```

Then, close and reopen your terminal and it should work :)